# Lambda function with 3 arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am using a lambda function to check the highest value, passing 3 arguments

```
from functools import reduce

# function to check bigger item
f = lambda a,b,c: a if (a > b) else (b if (b > c) else c)

# reduce function
reduce(f, [47, 11, 42, 102, 13])
```

However I get an error like this

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> 5 
> 6 # reduce function
> 7 reduce(f, [47, 11, 42, 102, 13, 21])
>
> TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
> ```

Comment: how many arguments do you think reduce passes? are you actually passing 3 args? (and if you think that that's not how it should work, just consider. lambda is just a way to write a function, but any function works. why should reduce be introspecting the function passed for number of args?)

Comment: `reduce` function expects/compares 2 items, not 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])

Apply function of **two arguments** cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

So, reduce is designed for functions with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the biggest elements in the list, compare three elements in once works in the same way as compare two elements in once. the two ways cost the same time. and even you make a function like `reduce` but takes 3 elements a time, there is a defect in your idea, because what if the list is composed of 4 or 6 or 8 or... elements, It still won't work as you expected.

```
from functools import reduce

# function to check bigger item
g = lambda a,b: a if (a > b) else b 
f(1,3,4)
# reduce function
reduce(g, [47, 11, 42, 102, 13])
```

Answer (score 1):

for checking the highest value use the build-in function max:

```
max([47, 11, 42, 102, 13])
```